# Fetch data from URL using PHP and show in the console by using javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I want to get data from the URL in the form of JSON and store in the variable of PHP. after it I want to call PHP variables in JS and show by console.log().

Comment: Add what you have tried in your question.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! [Right now, your question looks like a can I haz codes?-question](https://can-i-haz.codes) what is off-topic on SO. Either follow the steps on the first link, read **[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** or visit **[the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help)**. After that, edit your question accordingly. Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

your query is not clear. if you want to use php array variable in javascript and to console you can get idea from this,

```
  <?php
      $p= array("foo", "bar", "baz");
    ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    let app = <?php echo json_encode($p); ?>;
    console.log(app);
    </script>
```